# Manipulation of storm topology

Tags: graph, apache-storm

I'm new to Apache Storm..I'm trying to do something but I do not know if it's possible ..
I created a direct graph and I wanted to refer to the storm topology I am examining ... how can I connect the spout and the bolts with this graph? in order to do some analysis, like  pattern detection on the graph...is it possible? 
the graph code is here

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class DirectGraph<V> {
private Map<V, List<Edge<V>>> neighbors = new HashMap<V,   

List<Edge<V>>>();

public String toString() {
    StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();
    s.append("digraph G {");
    for (V v : neighbors.keySet()) {
        if (neighbors.get(v).size() > 0)
             for (Edge edge : neighbors.get(v)) {
                 s.append("\n  " + v + " -> " + edge);
             }
        else {
            continue;
        }
    }
    s.append("\n}");
    return s.toString();
}

public void add(V vertex) {

    if (neighbors.containsKey(vertex))
        return;
    neighbors.put(vertex, new ArrayList<Edge<V>>());
}

public void add(V from, V to, String label) {
    this.add(from);
    this.add(to);
    neighbors.get(from).add(new Edge<V>(to, label));
}

public static class Edge<V> {
    private V vertex;
    private String label;

    public Edge(V v, String l) {
        vertex = v;
        label = l;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return vertex + " [label=\"" + label + "\"];";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you're trying to do? What do you mean by "connect the spout and bolts with this graph"?

Comment: yes, I would like to analyze the storm topology with the some pattern but to do it I think that I must extract the topology in order to see it as a graph (DAG)
Can I extract the topology and visualize it in a DAG? 

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the topology DAG in a couple of ways.

When you are constructing your topology (e.g. with TopologyBuilder), you will get a `StormTopology` instance. This contains `SpoutSpec` and `BoltSpec` objects https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/8a475696e908c53f1c06bf1a8f373d8ac0483427/storm-client/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/generated/StormTopology.java#L45. Each of these contains a `ComponentCommon`, which contains a list of `inputs` and `streams` (outputs) https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/storm-client/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/generated/ComponentCommon.java#L39.

If you've already submitted the topology and it is running, you can get similar information by hitting the Storm UI server. The URL you want to retrieve is `<your-ui-host>/api/v1/topology/<your-topology-id>/visualization`

For example, here's the output I get when running a test topology locally, cleaned up a bit:

```
$ curl localhost:8080/api/v1/topology/wc-test-1-1548158863/visualization
{
  "split": {
    ":link": "\/component.html?id=split&topology_id=wc-test-1-1548158863",
    ":capacity": 0.1895867768595,
    ":type": "bolt",
    ":inputs": [
      {
        ":component": "spout",
        ":grouping": "shuffle",
        ":stream": "default",
        ":sani-stream": "default"
      }
    ],
  },
  "spout": {
    ":link": "\/component.html?id=spout&topology_id=wc-test-1-1548158863",
    ":capacity": 0,
    ":type": "spout",
    ":inputs": [
      {
        ":component": "__acker",
        ":grouping": "direct",
        ":stream": "__ack_reset_timeout",
        ":sani-stream": "_s__ack_reset_timeout"
      },
      {
        ":component": "__acker",
        ":grouping": "direct",
        ":stream": "__ack_ack",
        ":sani-stream": "_s__ack_ack"
      },
      {
        ":component": "__acker",
        ":grouping": "direct",
        ":stream": "__ack_fail",
        ":sani-stream": "_s__ack_fail"
      }
    ],
  },
  "count": {
    ":link": "\/component.html?id=count&topology_id=wc-test-1-1548158863",
    ":capacity": 0.22859504132231,
    ":type": "bolt",
    ":inputs": [
      {
        ":component": "split",
        ":grouping": "fields",
        ":stream": "default",
        ":sani-stream": "default"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see, I have one spout that is reading from the acker bolt, a "split" bolt that reads from the spout, and a "count" bolt that reads from the "split" bolt.

Comment: thank you! the first way is very good but maybe too difficult.. the second way is more easy..maybe :-)
I will try to do!